# Link to POST data that opens the result in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this link that makes a GET call to a controller method and opens the result in a new window:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My link text", "MyAction", "MyController", new {myData= Model.SomeField}, new { target= "_blank"})
```

It works but adds ?myData=xyz to query string. I want to convert this to a POST call so that myData will no longer be seen in the URL. How can I do that? Razor or javascript/jquery is fine as long as it works. I should also mention that there is already a form on the page, so I can't put the link in a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => Model.SomeField)
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to create another form, I have another form containing this and it would be form in a form which I think not good.